# parsing nested avro file

Tags: java, scala, hive, avro

I want to parse a nested avro file and want to load the same in a HIVE table (the HIVE table can be a nested table).

My AVRO schema look like below

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "NTTObject",
  "namespace" : "com.test.ntt",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "header",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "map",
      "values" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "avro.java.string" : "String"
      },
      "avro.java.string" : "String"
    },
    "default" : { }
  }, {
    "name" : "body",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "avro.java.string" : "String"
    },
    "default" : ""
  } ]
}
```

A sample data looks like below

```
{"objectKey":"trx/Phone/2016-05-12/15-12-18/0384bdr311-32w5b-49aa-a814-379256f80ca8"}   {"StatDataRequest":{"protocolVersion":"1","platform":"Android","format":"Detailed","deviceid":"0384bdr311-32w5b-49aa-a814-379256f80ca8","stats":{"clientStat":[{"contentActionStat":{"progid":"56aa31a135d1c95d77f70b533289dfc3","gen1re":"Sports/Auto/Racing/High-Def/Events/Series/Live","rating":"0","vendor":"1 1 877U3 50B","vod":"false","ppv":"false","series":"true","title":"Test Prix, Practice","description":"\"Test Prix, Practice\"","recordDate":"2016-05-26T12:00:00Z","channel":"220","channel_name":"NBCSHD","TMSID":"ABCD5544671291","channel_minor":"0","hd":"false","contentAction":"Streaming_Started","clientMode":"UNKNOWN","timestamp":"2016-05-27T03:00:28.686Z","errorReason":"36100530"}},{"contentActionStat":{"progid":"56aa31a135d1c95d77f70b533289dfc3","gen1re":"Sports/Auto/Racing/High-Def/Events/Series/Live","rating":"0","vendor":"1 1 875E3 50B","vod":"false","ppv":"false","series":"true","title":"Test Prix, Practice","description":"\"Test Prix, Practice\"","recordDate":"2016-05-26T12:00:00Z","channel":"220","channel_name":"NBCSHD","TMSID":"ABCD5544671291","channel_minor":"0","hd":"false","contentAction":"Streaming_Stopped","clientMode":"UNKNOWN","durationSeconds":"3172","timestamp":"2016-05-27T03:53:20.077Z","errorReason":"36100530"}}]}}}
```

Expected output for the above sample data (where PIPE (|) I have considered as column delimeter

```
trx/Phone/2016-05-12/15-12-18/0384bdr311-32w5b-49aa-a814-379256f80ca8|1|Android|Detailed|0384bdr311-32w5b-49aa-a814-379256f80ca8|56aa31a135d1c95d77f70b533289dfc3|Sports/Auto/Racing/High-Def/Events/Series/Live|0|1 1 877U3 50B|false|false|true|Test Prix, Practice|\"Test Prix, Practice\"|2016-05-26T12:00:00Z|220|NBCSHD|ABCD5544671291|0|false|Streaming_Started|UNKNOWN||2016-05-27T03:00:28.686Z|36100530
trx/Phone/2016-05-12/15-12-18/0384bdr311-32w5b-49aa-a814-379256f80ca8|1|Android|Detailed|0384bdr311-32w5b-49aa-a814-379256f80ca8|56aa31a135d1c95d77f70b533289dfc3|Sports/Auto/Racing/High-Def/Events/Series/Live|0|1 1 877U3 50B|false|false|true|Test Prix, Practice|\"Test Prix, Practice\"|2016-05-26T12:00:00Z|220|NBCSHD|ABCD5544671291|0|false|Streaming_Started|UNKNOWN|3172|2016-05-27T03:53:20.077Z|36100530
```

Any small sample code either in Java or Scala will be helpful

Code snippet used as suggested by **@SANN3**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class GenieGo_AVRO_Parsing {



    String jsonStr = "{\"objectKey\":\"trx/Android/2016-05-27/15-03-59/c496555a-940d-46eb-bc6a-21ae265ddf27\"}  {\"StatDataRequest\":{\"protocolVersion\":\"1\",\"platform\":\"Android\",\"format\":\"Detailed\",\"deviceid\":\"c496555a-940d-46eb-bc6a-21ae265ddf27\",\"stats\":{\"clientStat\":[{\"contentActionStat\":{\"progid\":\"481080bd93a0710e496335d9acceb6add1695e7b\",\"rating\":\"0\",\"vendor\":\"1 1 11AD3C 70\",\"vod\":\"false\",\"ppv\":\"false\",\"series\":\"true\",\"title\":\"Wienerschnitzel\",\"description\":\"Wienerschnitzel CEO Cynthia Galardi-Culpepper.\",\"recordDate\":\"2016-05-23T01:00:00Z\",\"channel\":\"11\",\"channel_name\":\"WTOL\",\"TMSID\":\"EP011584600112\",\"channel_minor\":\"65535\",\"hd\":\"false\",\"contentAction\":\"Downloading_Started\",\"clientMode\":\"UNKNOWN\",\"timestamp\":\"2016-05-26T02:44:43.511Z\"}},{\"contentActionStat\":{\"progid\":\"481080bd93a0710e496335d9acceb6add1695e7b\",\"rating\":\"0\",\"vendor\":\"1 1 11AD3C 70\",\"vod\":\"false\",\"ppv\":\"false\",\"series\":\"true\",\"title\":\"Wienerschnitzel\",\"description\":\"Wienerschnitzel CEO Cynthia Galardi-Culpepper.\",\"recordDate\":\"2016-05-23T01:00:00Z\",\"channel\":\"11\",\"channel_name\":\"WTOL\",\"TMSID\":\"EP011584600112\",\"channel_minor\":\"65535\",\"hd\":\"false\",\"contentAction\":\"Downloading_Finish\",\"clientMode\":\"UNKNOWN\",\"durationSeconds\":\"263\",\"timestamp\":\"2016-05-26T02:49:06.347Z\"}},{\"contentActionStat\":{\"progid\":\"481080bd93a0710e496335d9acceb6add1695e7b\",\"rating\":\"0\",\"vendor\":\"1 1 11AD3C 70\",\"vod\":\"false\",\"ppv\":\"false\",\"series\":\"true\",\"title\":\"Wienerschnitzel\",\"description\":\"Wienerschnitzel CEO Cynthia Galardi-Culpepper.\",\"recordDate\":\"2016-05-23T01:00:00Z\",\"channel\":\"11\",\"channel_name\":\"WTOL\",\"TMSID\":\"EP011584600112\",\"channel_minor\":\"65535\",\"hd\":\"false\",\"contentAction\":\"Downloading_Cancel\",\"clientMode\":\"UNKNOWN\",\"timestamp\":\"2016-05-26T02:49:06.349Z\"}},{\"contentActionStat\":{\"progid\":\"dcb1e7d2374d0c0fa35131dda7e9228421a07668\",\"rating\":\"0\",\"vendor\":\"1 1 11AD3C 71\",\"vod\":\"false\",\"ppv\":\"false\",\"series\":\"true\",\"title\":\"Golden Krust Caribbean Bakery & Grill\",\"description\":\"Golden Krust Caribbean Bakery & Grill CEO Lowell Hawthorne.\",\"recordDate\":\"2016-05-23T02:00:00Z\",\"channel\":\"11\",\"channel_name\":\"WTOL\",\"TMSID\":\"EP011584600113\",\"channel_minor\":\"65535\",\"hd\":\"false\",\"contentAction\":\"Downloading_Started\",\"clientMode\":\"UNKNOWN\",\"timestamp\":\"2016-05-26T02:49:16.382Z\"}},{\"contentActionStat\":{\"progid\":\"dcb1e7d2374d0c0fa35131dda7e9228421a07668\",\"rating\":\"0\",\"vendor\":\"1 1 11AD3C 71\",\"vod\":\"false\",\"ppv\":\"false\",\"series\":\"true\",\"title\":\"Golden Krust Caribbean Bakery & Grill\",\"description\":\"Golden Krust Caribbean Bakery & Grill CEO Lowell Hawthorne.\",\"recordDate\":\"2016-05-23T02:00:00Z\",\"channel\":\"11\",\"channel_name\":\"WTOL\",\"TMSID\":\"EP011584600113\",\"channel_minor\":\"65535\",\"hd\":\"false\",\"contentAction\":\"Downloading_Finish\",\"clientMode\":\"UNKNOWN\",\"durationSeconds\":\"254\",\"timestamp\":\"2016-05-26T02:53:30.368Z\"}},{\"contentActionStat\":{\"progid\":\"dcb1e7d2374d0c0fa35131dda7e9228421a07668\",\"rating\":\"0\",\"vendor\":\"1 1 11AD3C 71\",\"vod\":\"false\",\"ppv\":\"false\",\"series\":\"true\",\"title\":\"Golden Krust Caribbean Bakery & Grill\",\"description\":\"Golden Krust Caribbean Bakery & Grill CEO Lowell Hawthorne.\",\"recordDate\":\"2016-05-23T02:00:00Z\",\"channel\":\"11\",\"channel_name\":\"WTOL\",\"TMSID\":\"EP011584600113\",\"channel_minor\":\"65535\",\"hd\":\"false\",\"contentAction\":\"Downloading_Cancel\",\"clientMode\":\"UNKNOWN\",\"timestamp\":\"2016-05-26T02:53:30.373Z\"}}]}}}"; //Input JSON
            String json1 = jsonStr.substring(0, jsonStr.indexOf("}")+1);
            String json2 = jsonStr.substring(jsonStr.indexOf("}")+1);

            String out = "", header = "";
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(json1);
            header = header.concat(json.getString("objectKey")).concat("|");

            json = new JSONObject(json2);
            JSONObject StatDataRequest = json.getJSONObject("StatDataRequest");
            header = header.concat(StatDataRequest.getString("protocolVersion")).concat("|");
            header = header.concat(StatDataRequest.getString("platform")).concat("|");
            header = header.concat(StatDataRequest.getString("format")).concat("|");
            header = header.concat(StatDataRequest.getString("deviceid")).concat("|");
            JSONObject stats = StatDataRequest.getJSONObject("stats");
            JSONArray clientStatArr = stats.getJSONArray("clientStat");

            List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>();
            keyList.add("progid");
            keyList.add("gen1re");
            keyList.add("rating");
            keyList.add("vendor");
            keyList.add("vod");
            keyList.add("ppv");
            keyList.add("series");
            keyList.add("title");
            keyList.add("description");
            keyList.add("recordDate");
            keyList.add("channel");
            keyList.add("channel_name");
            keyList.add("TMSID");
            keyList.add("channel_minor");
            keyList.add("hd");
            keyList.add("contentAction");
            keyList.add("clientMode");
            keyList.add("timestamp");
            keyList.add("errorReason");

            String row;
            JSONObject clientStat, contentActionStat;
            for (int i = 0; i < clientStatArr.length(); i++) {
                clientStat = clientStatArr.getJSONObject(i);
                contentActionStat = clientStat.getJSONObject("contentActionStat");
                row = "";
                for (String key : keyList) {
                    row = row.concat(contentActionStat.getString(key)).concat("|");
                }
                out = out.concat(header).concat(row).concat("\n");
            }

            System.out.println(out);
       }
}
```

Comment: your sample data and schema does not match there no field header and body in sample data

Comment: The schema I have generated from the avro file itself using the command `java -jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/avro/avro-tools-1.7.6-cdh5.4.7.jar getschema part-m-00000 > geniego.avsc`

Comment: then your sample messages are not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find below two solutions that will produce the output you expect when using the provided data:

### 1. Jackson

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class ParserWithJackson {

    private static final String COLUMN_DELIMITER = "|";

    private static final String LINE_DELIMITER = "\r\n";

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public String parse(String input) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        String json1String = input.substring(0, input.indexOf("}") + 1).trim();
        String json2String = input.substring(input.indexOf("}") + 1).trim();

        JsonNode json1Tree = mapper.readTree(json1String);
        JsonNode json2Tree = mapper.readTree(json2String);

        JsonNode statDataRequestNode = json2Tree.get("StatDataRequest");
        JsonNode statsNode = statDataRequestNode.get("stats");
        JsonNode clientStatArray = statsNode.get("clientStat");

        String header = createHeaderData(json1Tree, json2Tree);

        for (JsonNode clientStatNode : clientStatArray) {

            JsonNode contentActionStatNode = clientStatNode.get("contentActionStat");

            output.append(header);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "progid"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "gen1re"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "rating"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "vendor"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "vod"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "ppv"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "series"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "title"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "description"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "recordDate"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "channel"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "channel_name"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "TMSID"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "channel_minor"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "hd"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "contentAction"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "clientMode"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "durationSeconds"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "timestamp"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "errorReason"));

            output.append(LINE_DELIMITER);
        }

        return output.toString();
    }

    private Object getContent(JsonNode node, String key) {

        JsonNode jsonNode = node.get(key);

        if (jsonNode == null) {
            return "";
        }
        return jsonNode.asText();
    }

    private String createHeaderData(JsonNode json1Tree, JsonNode json2Tree) {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.append(getContent(json1Tree, "objectKey"));
        builder.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

        JsonNode statDataRequestNode = json2Tree.get("StatDataRequest");

        builder.append(getContent(statDataRequestNode, "protocolVersion"));
        builder.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

        builder.append(getContent(statDataRequestNode, "platform"));
        builder.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

        builder.append(getContent(statDataRequestNode, "format"));
        builder.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

        builder.append(getContent(statDataRequestNode, "deviceid"));
        builder.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String input = "{\"objectKey\":\"trx/Phone/2016-05-12/15-12-18/0384bdr311-32w5b-49aa-a814-379256f80ca8\"}   {\"StatDataRequest\":{\"protocolVersion\":\"1\",\"platform\":\"Android\",\"format\":\"Detailed\",\"deviceid\":\"0384bdr311-32w5b-49aa-a814-379256f80ca8\",\"stats\":{\"clientStat\":[{\"contentActionStat\":{\"progid\":\"56aa31a135d1c95d77f70b533289dfc3\",\"gen1re\":\"Sports/Auto/Racing/High-Def/Events/Series/Live\",\"rating\":\"0\",\"vendor\":\"1 1 877U3 50B\",\"vod\":\"false\",\"ppv\":\"false\",\"series\":\"true\",\"title\":\"Test Prix, Practice\",\"description\":\"\\\"Test Prix, Practice\\\"\",\"recordDate\":\"2016-05-26T12:00:00Z\",\"channel\":\"220\",\"channel_name\":\"NBCSHD\",\"TMSID\":\"ABCD5544671291\",\"channel_minor\":\"0\",\"hd\":\"false\",\"contentAction\":\"Streaming_Started\",\"clientMode\":\"UNKNOWN\",\"timestamp\":\"2016-05-27T03:00:28.686Z\",\"errorReason\":\"36100530\"}},{\"contentActionStat\":{\"progid\":\"56aa31a135d1c95d77f70b533289dfc3\",\"gen1re\":\"Sports/Auto/Racing/High-Def/Events/Series/Live\",\"rating\":\"0\",\"vendor\":\"1 1 875E3 50B\",\"vod\":\"false\",\"ppv\":\"false\",\"series\":\"true\",\"title\":\"Test Prix, Practice\",\"description\":\"\\\"Test Prix, Practice\\\"\",\"recordDate\":\"2016-05-26T12:00:00Z\",\"channel\":\"220\",\"channel_name\":\"NBCSHD\",\"TMSID\":\"ABCD5544671291\",\"channel_minor\":\"0\",\"hd\":\"false\",\"contentAction\":\"Streaming_Stopped\",\"clientMode\":\"UNKNOWN\",\"durationSeconds\":\"3172\",\"timestamp\":\"2016-05-27T03:53:20.077Z\",\"errorReason\":\"36100530\"}}]}}}";

        ParserWithJackson parser = new ParserWithJackson();
        String output = parser.parse(input);

        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Dependencies:

- [`jackson-core-2.8.0.jar`](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.8.0/)
- [`jackson-databind-2.8.0.jar`](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.8.0/)
- [`jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar`](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.8.0/)

### 2. JSON.org

```java
import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class ParserWithJsonOrg {

    private static final String COLUMN_DELIMITER = "|";

    private static final String LINE_DELIMITER = "\r\n";

    public String parse(String input) {

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        String json1String = input.substring(0, input.indexOf("}") + 1).trim();
        String json2String = input.substring(input.indexOf("}") + 1).trim();

        JSONObject json1Tree = new JSONObject(json1String);
        JSONObject json2Tree = new JSONObject(json2String);

        JSONObject statDataRequestNode = json2Tree.getJSONObject("StatDataRequest");
        JSONObject statsNode = statDataRequestNode.getJSONObject("stats");
        JSONArray clientStatArray = statsNode.getJSONArray("clientStat");

        String header = createHeaderData(json1Tree, json2Tree);

        for (int i = 0; i < clientStatArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject clientStatNode = clientStatArray.getJSONObject(i);

            JSONObject contentActionStatNode = clientStatNode.getJSONObject("contentActionStat");

            output.append(header);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "progid"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "gen1re"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "rating"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "vendor"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "vod"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "ppv"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "series"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "title"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "description"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "recordDate"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "channel"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "channel_name"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "TMSID"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "channel_minor"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "hd"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "contentAction"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "clientMode"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "durationSeconds"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "timestamp"));
            output.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

            output.append(getContent(contentActionStatNode, "errorReason"));

            output.append(LINE_DELIMITER);
        }

        return output.toString();
    }

    private Object getContent(JSONObject jsonObject, String key) {

        Object object = null;

        try {
            object = jsonObject.get(key);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            object = "";
        }

        return object;
    }

    private String createHeaderData(JSONObject json1Tree, JSONObject json2Tree) {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.append(getContent(json1Tree, "objectKey"));
        builder.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

        JSONObject statDataRequestNode = json2Tree.getJSONObject("StatDataRequest");

        builder.append(getContent(statDataRequestNode, "protocolVersion"));
        builder.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

        builder.append(getContent(statDataRequestNode, "platform"));
        builder.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

        builder.append(getContent(statDataRequestNode, "format"));
        builder.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

        builder.append(getContent(statDataRequestNode, "deviceid"));
        builder.append(COLUMN_DELIMITER);

        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String input = "{\"objectKey\":\"trx/Phone/2016-05-12/15-12-18/0384bdr311-32w5b-49aa-a814-379256f80ca8\"}   {\"StatDataRequest\":{\"protocolVersion\":\"1\",\"platform\":\"Android\",\"format\":\"Detailed\",\"deviceid\":\"0384bdr311-32w5b-49aa-a814-379256f80ca8\",\"stats\":{\"clientStat\":[{\"contentActionStat\":{\"progid\":\"56aa31a135d1c95d77f70b533289dfc3\",\"gen1re\":\"Sports/Auto/Racing/High-Def/Events/Series/Live\",\"rating\":\"0\",\"vendor\":\"1 1 877U3 50B\",\"vod\":\"false\",\"ppv\":\"false\",\"series\":\"true\",\"title\":\"Test Prix, Practice\",\"description\":\"\\\"Test Prix, Practice\\\"\",\"recordDate\":\"2016-05-26T12:00:00Z\",\"channel\":\"220\",\"channel_name\":\"NBCSHD\",\"TMSID\":\"ABCD5544671291\",\"channel_minor\":\"0\",\"hd\":\"false\",\"contentAction\":\"Streaming_Started\",\"clientMode\":\"UNKNOWN\",\"timestamp\":\"2016-05-27T03:00:28.686Z\",\"errorReason\":\"36100530\"}},{\"contentActionStat\":{\"progid\":\"56aa31a135d1c95d77f70b533289dfc3\",\"gen1re\":\"Sports/Auto/Racing/High-Def/Events/Series/Live\",\"rating\":\"0\",\"vendor\":\"1 1 875E3 50B\",\"vod\":\"false\",\"ppv\":\"false\",\"series\":\"true\",\"title\":\"Test Prix, Practice\",\"description\":\"\\\"Test Prix, Practice\\\"\",\"recordDate\":\"2016-05-26T12:00:00Z\",\"channel\":\"220\",\"channel_name\":\"NBCSHD\",\"TMSID\":\"ABCD5544671291\",\"channel_minor\":\"0\",\"hd\":\"false\",\"contentAction\":\"Streaming_Stopped\",\"clientMode\":\"UNKNOWN\",\"durationSeconds\":\"3172\",\"timestamp\":\"2016-05-27T03:53:20.077Z\",\"errorReason\":\"36100530\"}}]}}}";

        ParserWithJsonOrg parser = new ParserWithJsonOrg();
        String output = parser.parse(input);

        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Dependency:

- [`json-20160212.jar`](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20160212/)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. Assign your input json to **jsonStr** variable. Dependency is **json-20160212.jar**

```
   String jsonStr = "{\"objectKey\":\"trx/Phone/2016-05-12/15-12-18/0384bdr311-32w5b-49aa-a814-379256f80ca8\"}   {\"StatDataRequest\":{\"protocolVersion\":\"1\",\"platform\":\"Android\",\"format\":\"Detailed\",\"deviceid\":\"0384bdr311-32w5b-49aa-a814-379256f80ca8\",\"stats\":{\"clientStat\":[{\"contentActionStat\":{\"progid\":\"56aa31a135d1c95d77f70b533289dfc3\",\"gen1re\":\"Sports/Auto/Racing/High-Def/Events/Series/Live\",\"rating\":\"0\",\"vendor\":\"1 1 877U3 50B\",\"vod\":\"false\",\"ppv\":\"false\",\"series\":\"true\",\"title\":\"Test Prix, Practice\",\"description\":\"\\\"Test Prix, Practice\\\"\",\"recordDate\":\"2016-05-26T12:00:00Z\",\"channel\":\"220\",\"channel_name\":\"NBCSHD\",\"TMSID\":\"ABCD5544671291\",\"channel_minor\":\"0\",\"hd\":\"false\",\"contentAction\":\"Streaming_Started\",\"clientMode\":\"UNKNOWN\",\"timestamp\":\"2016-05-27T03:00:28.686Z\",\"errorReason\":\"36100530\"}},{\"contentActionStat\":{\"progid\":\"56aa31a135d1c95d77f70b533289dfc3\",\"gen1re\":\"Sports/Auto/Racing/High-Def/Events/Series/Live\",\"rating\":\"0\",\"vendor\":\"1 1 875E3 50B\",\"vod\":\"false\",\"ppv\":\"false\",\"series\":\"true\",\"title\":\"Test Prix, Practice\",\"description\":\"\\\"Test Prix, Practice\\\"\",\"recordDate\":\"2016-05-26T12:00:00Z\",\"channel\":\"220\",\"channel_name\":\"NBCSHD\",\"TMSID\":\"ABCD5544671291\",\"channel_minor\":\"0\",\"hd\":\"false\",\"contentAction\":\"Streaming_Stopped\",\"clientMode\":\"UNKNOWN\",\"durationSeconds\":\"3172\",\"timestamp\":\"2016-05-27T03:53:20.077Z\",\"errorReason\":\"36100530\"}}]}}}";
    String json1 = jsonStr.substring(0, jsonStr.indexOf("}")+1);
    String json2 = jsonStr.substring(jsonStr.indexOf("}")+1);

    String out = "", header = "";
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(json1);
    header = header.concat(json.getString("objectKey")).concat("|");

    json = new JSONObject(json2);
    JSONObject StatDataRequest = json.getJSONObject("StatDataRequest");
    header = header.concat(StatDataRequest.getString("protocolVersion")).concat("|");
    header = header.concat(StatDataRequest.getString("platform")).concat("|");
    header = header.concat(StatDataRequest.getString("format")).concat("|");
    header = header.concat(StatDataRequest.getString("deviceid")).concat("|");
    JSONObject stats = StatDataRequest.getJSONObject("stats");
    JSONArray clientStatArr = stats.getJSONArray("clientStat");

    List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>();
    keyList.add("progid");
    keyList.add("gen1re");
    keyList.add("rating");
    keyList.add("vendor");
    keyList.add("vod");
    keyList.add("ppv");
    keyList.add("series");
    keyList.add("title");
    keyList.add("description");
    keyList.add("recordDate");
    keyList.add("channel");
    keyList.add("channel_name");
    keyList.add("TMSID");
    keyList.add("channel_minor");
    keyList.add("hd");
    keyList.add("contentAction");
    keyList.add("clientMode");
    keyList.add("timestamp");
    keyList.add("errorReason");

    String row;
    JSONObject clientStat, contentActionStat;
    for (int i = 0; i < clientStatArr.length(); i++) {
        clientStat = clientStatArr.getJSONObject(i);
        contentActionStat = clientStat.getJSONObject("contentActionStat");
        row = "";
        for (String key : keyList) {
            row = row.concat(contentActionStat.getString(key)).concat("|");
        }
        out = out.concat(header).concat(row).concat("\n");
    }

    System.out.println(out);
```

Comment: I have downloaded `json-20160212.jar` from `https://www.versioneye.com/java/org.json:json/20160212`. But for no reason getting syntax error `Description Resource Path Location Type
Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token GenieGo_AVRO_Parsing.java /AVRO-Parsing/src line 16 Java Problem` on line `JSONObject json = new JSONObject(json1);`

Comment: Code snippet given in the original post.

Comment: The error I am getting is `Description Resource Path Location Type
Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token GenieGo_AVRO_Parsing.java /AVRO-Parsing/src line 16 Java Problem`
`JSONObject json = new JSONObject(json1);`

Comment: @KoushikChandra there is error in your jsonStr variable. Updated in my code. Please verify it.